# Eigenvalues/vectors of a slightly changed matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Hi Math StackExchange,

I have a large time-dependent matrix that has fluctuating values on the diagonal and constant off-diagonal values. Suppose I have diagonalized the matrix with some initial diagonal. Is there a way to approximate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a new matrix with the same off-diagonal values and (slightly) different diagonal values without re-diagonalizing it from scratch? The physical situation here is a Hamiltonian with fluctuating vibrational frequencies and constant vibrational couplings.

Thank you!

Comment: What size is the matrid

Comment: 3000x3000 roughly

Comment: Have you looked into perturbation theory of matrices?

Comment: i have looked into it, and it is exactly what I was looking for. thank you KBS!